# Insertion Sorts how to print the whole array

Tags: java, sorting

I would like to know how can I show in the output the step by step process of Insertion Sorts. If I put `20,5,9,8,7` the output is `5,7,8,9,20`.  It's not showing the step by step process, how can I show that? Here is my code:

```
for(i=0; i<r; i++) {
    System.out.print(data[i]+"\t");
}

System.out.print("\n");

for (j=1; j<r;j++) {
    temp = data[j];
    for( i=j-1; i>=0 && temp < data[i]; i--)
    data[i+1]= data[i];
    data[i+1]=temp;
}

for(j=0; j<r; j++) {
    System.out.print(data[j]+"\t");
    System.out.print("\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: This depends entirely on what you mean by step by step. Which steps?

Comment: You could print the whole list after every change, your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Regretfully, I have not been able to get this code to sort anything for me...aka, I cannot reproduce the output.  Can you post a *slightly* more complete example?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

> its not showing the step by step process, how can I show that?

I would use a combination of [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) and formatted output with [`printf(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = { 20, 5, 9, 8, 7 };
    System.out.println("Before sort: " + Arrays.toString(data));
    sort(data);
    System.out.println("After sort: " + Arrays.toString(data));
}

public static void sort(int[] data) {
    int i;
    for (int j = 1, r = data.length; j < r; j++) {
        int temp = data[j];
        System.out.printf("Sorting %d from pos=%d%n", temp, j);
        for (i = j - 1; i >= 0 && temp < data[i]; i--) {
            data[i + 1] = data[i];
            System.out.printf("%d is less then %d, shifting up%n", tehmp,
                    data[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("%d moved from pos=%d to pos=%d%n", temp, j,
                i + 1);
        data[i + 1] = temp;
        System.out.printf("After iteration %d: %s%n", j,
                Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}
```